# Calling Win32 Interprocess Semaphore or Event rapidly

Tags: c++, winapi, events, interprocess, win32-process

Assume that two spawned processes signaling using **Win32** Events or semaphore,but When an event has be signal and reset within between **1 to 10 millisecond** time interval.Sometimes Event set function - [SetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211(v=vs.85).aspx) failed to signal.

If every ,

***SETEvent -> WAITFOSINGLEOBJECT/RESETEVENT -> SETEvent***

calls happens rapidly ,

1. Will Win32 Kernel event or Semaphore objects fails to propagate or
   signal among each two processes ?
2. Is there better alternatives to rapid signaling among Windows
   inter-process?

(One Process is set/reset event other one waiting until signaled)
(We can emulate Event behavior using Semaphores using single count)

Comment: This is basically what `PulseEvent` does and yes it can miss events. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050105-00/?p=36803 for a discussion on this.

Comment: @JonathanPotter PulseEvent is deprecated right? Is  it safe to use <code>PulseEvent</code> ?

Comment: @Buddhika - SetEvent not failed. failed only your program logic. use `PulseEvent` is safe. but it not help you by same logic problem

Comment: It is drastically troublesome, you'll almost inevitably have a race condition in your program.  You cannot assume that the other thread/process has properly completed the WFSO call.  You need two synchronization objects so you can correctly ping-pong back and forth.

Comment: @HansPassant  Process1 which is set the event  cannot depend on other process2 wait object, in process1 assume we have a loop and within that it resetting and setting the event  for every delta(small duration) millisecond , and procees 2 also spawn a thread and that thread on a loop ,within that loop it wait for signal from process 1 and consecutively do some push back operations and wait again for signal from process 1. what ever happens in process 2 , process 1 should signaling for given time interval,within a cycle of process 1's loop ,process 2 capture a signal and do stuff and wait again.